# php input value changed and UPDATE database

Tags: php, html, database, mysqli

The Note field is updateable and you should highlight it in yellow. All other columns are Non-updateable fields.
the Note was updated, I should update the
Note column of the corresponding record in database table. A message “The Note for code xxxx has
been updated in the database.” should be displayed for each updated record.

here is my code for table note

```
while($tablerow=mysqli_fetch_array($tableresult)){
        $amt=$tablerow['amount'];
        if($amt>'0'){
        $aColor='style="color:blue;"';
        }else{
        $aColor='style="color:red;"';
        }

        $operation="";
        if($tablerow['type']=='W'){
        $operation="Withdraw";
        }
        if($tablerow['type']=='D'){
        $operation="Deposit";
        }

        $source="";
        if($tablerow['sid']==1){
            $source="ATM";
        }else if($tablerow['sid']==2){
            $source="Online";
        }else if($tablerow['sid']==3){
            $source="Branch";
        }else{$source="Wired";
            }
        echo"
    <tr><td align='center'><input type='hidden' name='mid[".$i."]' value='".$tablerow['mid']."'>".$tablerow['mid']."</td>
        <td align='center'><input type='hidden' name='code[".$i."]' value='".$tablerow['code']."'>".$tablerow['code']."</td>
        <td align='center'".$aColor."><input type='hidden' name='amount[".$i."]' value='".$amt."'>".$amt."</td>
        <td align='center'><input type='hidden' name='type[".$i."]' value='".$operation."'>".$operation."</td>
        <td align='center'><input type='hidden' name='source[".$i."]' value='".$source."'>".$source."</td>
        <td align='center'><input type='hidden' name='date[".$i."]' value='".$tablerow['mydatetime']."'>".$tablerow['mydatetime']."</td>
        <td align='center' bgcolor='yellow'><input type='text' name='note[".$i."]' style='background-color:yellow' value='".$tablerow['note']."'></td>
        <td align='center'><input type='checkbox' name='delete[".$i."]' value='Y'></td></tr>\n";
        $i++;
    }

    echo "Total balance: $".$totalrow['total']."<br>";

    echo"<input type='submit' value='Update transaction'></form>";
    echo "</table>\n";

    echo "Total balance: $".$totalrow['total']."<br>";

    echo"<input type='submit' value='Update transaction'></form>";
```

this is code where I am struggling

```
for($i=0; $i<$tablerow; $i++){
    if(isset($_POST['note'][$i])){
        $note=$_POST['note'][$i];
        $mid=$_POST['mid'][$i];
        mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE Money set note='$note' where mid='$mid' and note!='$note';");
        echo"Successfully update transaction code: UPDATE Money_kimeunb set note='".$note."' where id=".$mid." and note !='".$note."'<br>";
    }
```

but since I already have value in the input of note, it updates all values of table not only where I want to update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your query is updating all notes where the "note" content is NOT equal to the posted "note".

I noticed you passed a code with your post data, I am assuming this is a column in your database also which is associated with this specific note. IF this is a unique value. You could change

```
mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE Money set note='$note' where mid='$mid' and note!='$note';");
```

to

```
mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE Money set note='$note' where mid='$mid' and code ='$code';");
```

You would of course need to define $code

This is of course assuming that Code is unique here? Otherwise the easiest way to achieve this would be to use a unique index such as the row id.

In which case you could write:

```
mysql_query($con,"UPDATE Money set note='$note' where id='$id';");
```

Obviously again you would need to define $id here.

But please be aware, that when using hidden values in a form which are used as indexes it is very easy for someone to put data in a post that doesn't belong to that user, you would always want some sort of validation to ensure ownership before you would consider updating.

Comment: Thank you for response!